# Ubuntu shutting down by itself

Tags: 20.10

I had installed Ubuntu on a VM, so that I move to it some apps I use on Windows.

But it seems that if I stay afk from the VM for some time, it shuts down. When I go us use it, the VM is powered off. It's not some hybernation or standby, because when I start the VM it runs the full startup and no app is opened anymore.

What could be causing it and how to disable it so that it stays on?

Update: here's the log, I've found nothing explaining why the shutdown happened.

```
systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revisi>
systemd[1]: snap-snapd-8542.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 85>
systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeed>
systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File System>
systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
systemd[1]: Shutting down.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devi>
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining proce>
VGAuthService[613]: Processing SIGTERM; service exiting
VGAuthService[613]: ServiceEndMainLoop: about to stop m>
VGAuthService[613]: END SERVICE
systemd-journald[366]: Journal stopped
lines 981-1003/1003 (END)
systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 467.
systemd[1]: snap-snapd-8542.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 8542.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
systemd[1]: Shutting down.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
VGAuthService[613]: Processing SIGTERM; service exiting
VGAuthService[613]: ServiceEndMainLoop: about to stop main loop
VGAuthService[613]: END SERVICE
systemd-journald[366]: Journal stopped
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 981-1003/1003 (END)
systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 467.
systemd[1]: snap-snapd-8542.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 8542.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
systemd[1]: Shutting down.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
VGAuthService[613]: Processing SIGTERM; service exiting
VGAuthService[613]: ServiceEndMainLoop: about to stop main loop
VGAuthService[613]: END SERVICE
systemd-journald[366]: Journal stopped
```

Comment: Look at the logs. Read `man journalctl`. `sudo journalctl  -b  -1 -e` will show the end of the previous boot's logs.

Comment: graphics... but... I'd look into the logs like suggested

Comment: tnx, I updated the question with the log